# I can't run my applet program on browser why?

Tags: java, applet, japplet

Just want to try running applet on my browser, so I made a simple program:

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class NotHelloWorldApplet extends JApplet {
    public void init() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                JLabel label = new JLabel("Hello World applet",    SwingConstants.CENTER);
                add(label);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

And here is my HTML file:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title> Hello World Applet</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <applet code=“HelloWorldApplet.class” width=“300” height=“300”>
        </applet>
    </body>
</html>
```

And here is my browser configuration:
[image: Java plugins]

Everything looks great, but when I run my HTML file, it doesn't work. It simply show the content:
[image: Applets]

I can view it on Eclipse, just cannot view it on the browser. Is there anything I made it wrong?

Comment: You need to open it as a HTML file. How are you currently opening it, and what's the file called?

Comment: Yes, I open the HTML file, and it is in the same file as my class file. The HTML file I simply named it "HelloWorldApplet" same as my class file name

Comment: Try renaming your file to `HelloWorldApplet.html`

Comment: I just renamed it, but show the same thing. But it is already html extension, I don't think rename it will change anything.

Comment: Which browser are you using?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Ok, when I open the HTML file on Dreamweaver, the HTML file oddly appear lots of extra lines. I don't know why, but I made the HTML file via TextEditor in the first place, I guess it is just not a qualified "HTML editor". Therefore, I redo a HTML file on Dreamweaver, and it works. Lesson learned, don't trust TextEditor to make a HTML file, because it might have some hidden content.

Comment: Glad you got it working, but this answer is just nonsense.  I regularly create HTML in a text editor and it introduces absolutely nothing beyond what I put in it. DreamWeaver OTOH will likely add all the cruft.

Answer (score 1):

1. Save it as `file.html`
2. Open it through your web browser

Can you open other HTML files from your browser?